# Objective C Asynchronous to Synchronous Database Access

Tags: sql, swift, asynchronous

I have found an open source Objective-C library for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server databases.

The problem is, that I would like to use it synchronously.

This is how my Swift project uses the library.

```
func execute(query: String) {

    self.client.connect(host + ":" + port, username: username, password: password, database: database) { (connected) -> Void in
        if connected {
            self.client.execute(query, completion: { (results: Array<AnyObject>!) -> Void in
                self.result = results[0] as! Array<AnyObject>
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The block passed is execute asynchronously by the library.  Is there a way to make the code execute synchronously so that whenever I call `execute`, that thread waits for the library work to complete before `execute` returns?

Comment: I connect to a extern microsoft sql server

Comment: What's your goal? Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: What kind of MSSQL library are you using?

Comment: Preferably Swift but if that doesnt work than with objective c if possible

Comment: https://github.com/martinrybak/SQLClient

Comment: If you make the connection synchronous to a server over the Internet the app will become non-responsive until the connection completes or times-out. Basically that is unacceptable.

Comment: I highly recommend you check out my [SQLConnect](https://github.com/nhgrif/SQLConnect) library rather than using Martin's... this block based approach is a major pain.  My library takes a delegate approach and makes for much clearer cleaner looking code.  I've also resolved several of the problems that Martin's library still has...

Comment: @zaph This is only true if he's making it synchronous on the UI thread.  Perhaps he wants to make it synchronous on a thread which is already in the background.  It's a fair warning, but synchronous and blocking the UI thread do not mean the same thing, let's be clear.

Answer (score 11):

So, I have some experience with the github library you're using.

It seems most likely that you might want to make this call synchronously because of some of the problems this library has (you can't make multiple queries at once, and can't open multiple connections to the server because the library does all of its SQL work through a singleton).  To resolve some of these problems, I highly recommend you check out the [SQLConnect library](https://github.com/nhgrif/SQLConnect) that I wrote (after spending some time trying to use Martin's library that you're using).  My library steps away from the singleton approach and you can make as many connections on as many different threads as you want.

With that said... you *can* make this library (and mine as well) perform synchronously.

If you notice in the [`SQLClient.h` file](https://github.com/martinrybak/SQLClient/blob/master/SQLClient/SQLClient/SQLClient/SQLClient.h), the `SQLClient` object specifies a `workerQueue` and a `callbackQueue`.  Martin has set the `callbackQueue` to be on whatever queue the singleton is first instantiated on, and the `workerQueue` is a queue he specifies.  However, these are public properties which can be set perfectly fine.

If you *really* want the query to perform synchronously, just set the `workerQueue` and `callbackQueue` to operate on the current queue.

```
SQLClient.sharedInstance.workerQueue = NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()
SQLClient.sharedInstance.callbackQueue = NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()
```

And then perform your query.

All of the code will execute on the same `NSOperationQueue`, and as such, will by synchronous.

Of course, you can do the same thing using [my SQLConnect library](https://github.com/nhgrif/SQLConnect), as [the `SQLConnection` object](https://github.com/nhgrif/SQLConnect/blob/master/SQLConnect/SQLConnection/SQLConnection.h) similarly specifies a `workerQueue` and `callbackQueue` which you can specify to any queue you want.

With *all* of this said, I highly, highly, highly recommend that you allow the operation to remain asynchronous and come up with some other solution to whatever problem makes you think it should be performing synchronously.  And even if you still think it should by synchronous, please be sure it's not blocking the UI thread.